# Cannot resolve a symbol for use as a generic type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to create a new instance of a class from the Type which is found via reflection.  When calling TableInsert() 'destType' cannot be resolved and when used as a parameter for the method, I get this error: "Argument type 'System.Type' is not assignable to parameter type 'destType.'" I have a feeling the answer to this is extremely simple and I've just been staring at the code far too long.

```
//this is executed first
private void ImportData(IDataMapping tableMap)
{
    //destType is a class of POCOs that match column names from a database table
    //the class inherits from a base class called SchemaObject which inherits from ISchemaObject which itself inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged
    //an example name would be 'SchemaEmployees' where employees is the destination table name
    Type destType = typeof(ISchemaObject).Assembly.GetTypes()
                    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.ToLower() == "schema" + tableMap.tableName.ToLower());

    if (destType == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("Could not find class mapping for table " + tableMap.tableName + ".");

    //the list of public properties on the POCO class, i.e. the columns from the database table
    List<PropertyInfo> destProps = destType.GetProperties().ToList();

    //here I create a DataSet from a DataAdapter for the destination insert table 
    //here I get a DbDataReader from a source database and run ExecuteReader()
    using (DataSet ds = GetTableDs())
    using (DbDataReader reader = GetSourceData())
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            TableInsert<destType>(tableMap, reader, ds, destType, destProps);
        }
}  

//this is where the DataRow for the destination database is created and the columns mapped to the class POCOs
private void TableInsert<T>(
    IDataMapping tableMap,
    DbDataReader r, //source
    DataSet ds, //destination
    T destClassType,
    IList<PropertyInfo> destClassProperties) 
    where T : ISchemaObject
{
    var dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();

    var dest = dr.CreateItemFromRow<destClassType>(destClassProperties) as ISchemaObject;

    //sets the DataRow column value when the class property value changes
    dest.PropertyChanged += (sender, eArgs) =>
    {
        dr[eArgs.PropertyName] =
            destClassType
            .GetType()
            .GetProperty(eArgs.PropertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(sender, null);
    };

    //the source DataReader row is converted to a Dynamic class
    //it's not type safe, but the source changes frequently so properly mapping it would add undue complexity to the project        
    var srcEnt = new DynamicEntityGenerator.DataReaderEntity(r);

    dynamic dynSrc = srcEnt;

    //in this method the destination class (bound to the DataRow that will be inserted) properties are mapped to the source Dynamic class's properties
    tableMap.MapInsertClasses<ISchemaObject>(dynSrc, dest);

    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
}  

//DataRow extension method for mapping the row to a class containing properties with the same name as the DataColumn names
public static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(
    this DataRow row,
    IList<PropertyInfo> properties)
    where T : new()
{
    T item = new T();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (row[property.Name] != DBNull.Value)
            property.SetValue(item, row[property.Name], null);
    }

    return item;
}
```

Comment: Generics don't work like that. You need a type *name* within the `<>`, not a variable

Comment: You are confusing a data type with a Type object.  With generic types, everything is fixed at compile time.  With Reflection, everything is determined at run time.  If you start down the Reflection road then you must keep going down that road.

Comment: If I change the code to TableInsert<SchemaObject>(tableMap, reader, ds, destType, destProps), I get "Argument 'System.Type' is not assignable to parameter type Schemas.SchemaObject." I realize what it's saying but not sure how to fix it. The second issue is when calling dr.CreateItemFromRow<T>() that I don't know the specific class that I want a new instance of, (well, I have the Type) only that it inherits from SchemaObject. Edit- jmcilhinney you're saying I should use Activator.CreateInstance and forgo generics?

Comment: Something else regarding the solution you are using... you can just use Typed Datasets that work like the POCOs you are trying to create. I wouldn't recommend it but it's better than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use generics in that way, but you actually don't need it. You can do:

```
//this is executed first
private void ImportData(IDataMapping tableMap)
{
    //destType is a class of POCOs that match column names from a database table
    //the class inherits from a base class called SchemaObject which inherits from ISchemaObject which itself inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged
    //an example name would be 'SchemaEmployees' where employees is the destination table name
    Type destType = typeof(ISchemaObject).Assembly.GetTypes()
                    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.ToLower() == "schema" + tableMap.tableName.ToLower());

    if (destType == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("Could not find class mapping for table " + tableMap.tableName + ".");

    //the list of public properties on the POCO class, i.e. the columns from the database table
    List<PropertyInfo> destProps = destType.GetProperties().ToList();

    //here I create a DataSet from a DataAdapter for the destination insert table 
    //here I get a DbDataReader from a source database and run ExecuteReader()
    using (DataSet ds = GetTableDs())
    using (DbDataReader reader = GetSourceData())
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            TableInsert(tableMap, reader, ds, destType, destProps);
        }
}  

//this is where the DataRow for the destination database is created and the columns mapped to the class POCOs
private void TableInsert(
    IDataMapping tableMap,
    DbDataReader r, //source
    DataSet ds, //destination
    Type destClassType,
    IList<PropertyInfo> destClassProperties)
{
    var dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();

    var dest = dr.CreateItemFromRow(destClassType, destClassProperties) as ISchemaObject;

    //sets the DataRow column value when the class property value changes
    dest.PropertyChanged += (sender, eArgs) =>
    {
        dr[eArgs.PropertyName] =
            destClassType
            .GetType()
            .GetProperty(eArgs.PropertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .GetValue(sender, null);
    };

    //the source DataReader row is converted to a Dynamic class
    //it's not type safe, but the source changes frequently so properly mapping it would add undue complexity to the project        
    var srcEnt = new DynamicEntityGenerator.DataReaderEntity(r);

    dynamic dynSrc = srcEnt;

    //in this method the destination class (bound to the DataRow that will be inserted) properties are mapped to the source Dynamic class's properties
    tableMap.MapInsertClasses<ISchemaObject>(dynSrc, dest);

    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
}  

//DataRow extension method for mapping the row to a class containing properties with the same name as the DataColumn names
public static ISchemaObject CreateItemFromRow(
    this DataRow row,
    Type type,
    IList<PropertyInfo> properties)
{
    var item = (ISchemaObject)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (row[property.Name] != DBNull.Value)
            property.SetValue(item, row[property.Name], null);
    }

    return item;
}
```

You can also validate that the type is actually a `ISchemaObject` and has a parameterless constructor if you need to.

Comment: This works, the only issue is with the dependencies. By adding a dependency to code in my project, I can't keep this extension method where it currently resides. Not a big deal though. Thank you!